# Modifying table structure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table member with some fields

```
member_id    Primary key
last_name    nvarchar
first_name   nvarchar
address      nvarchar
city phone   number
join_date    date
```

I would like change the field join_date that can have to store the date automatically

so 
I just use this

```
alter table member
modify column (join_date varchar2 default constraints dt sysdate notnull);
```

but it retuns an error that is ora:00907 missing right paranthesis.

Comment: Why would you want to save date as `varchar`? what is your RDBMS?

Comment: ORA == Oracle...(although given the 30 char limit of column and table names maybe Ora'ble)

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table member
modify column (join_date varchar2 default constraints dt sysdate not null);
```

I think you are missing a space between 'not' and 'null'

Comment: Thanks David pilkingston

Comment: @user3077239 Not a problem, if this answered the question please accept that answer so that the issue can be closed

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this(Add a space between **notnull**):

```
alter table member
modify column (join_date varchar2 default constraints dt sysdate not null);
                                                                    ^^__space here
```

Comment: I'm not an oracle expert - doesn't this changes also changes the column type?

Comment: @Yosi:- Yes but since OP has not mentioned why he is doing so the present query which OP has shown has the problem which I have highlighted. P.S. Initially the question was not tagged properly! :)

Comment: OK, an important note for the OP: saving dates as strings is (mostly) a very bad practice, and you should have a very good reason for doing that.

Comment: @Yosi:- A very genuine and important note.! +1